# Dotnet Run In VSCode Socket Exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, sockets, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm Using **dotnet run** to start a ASP.Net core WebApi Project in my solution in **VS Code**
after executing the command , I received below exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10049): The requested address is not valid in its context.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportOptions.CreateDefaultBoundListenSocket(EndPoint endpoint)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig endpointConfig, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at NGDIR.WebApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\FarshadFahimi\Documents\Projects\NGDIR_MSD_BACK\src\WebApi\Program.cs:line 36
   at NGDIR.WebApi.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

How can I fix this ???

Comment: Where's the exception? I see the stack trace but not the exception

Comment: @davidfowl sorry , it didn't paste completely
The exception is : 
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10049): The requested address is not valid in its context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the lunch port may be helpful. You can do it by the command:
***dotnet run --launch-profile  xxx***

Comment: It worked but how should not use it in every time I wanna run my development environment???
There is a place to config this launch profile that any time I want to run , I use ** dotnet run ** only ??

Comment: Using dotnet run is not the only way, I see you are using the VSCode, so environment variables can be set in the file: .vscode/launch.json, adding the "env":{"ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://localhost:xxxx"}. If you want more information about it, this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2) can help you. If my answer is helpful, please give me a mark. Thank you!